# Trying to scrape a website using API Calls

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the website https://www.jobijoba.com/fr/query/?what=&where=Ile-de-france&where_type=region using API calls in python. I am using the requests library to send requests. But unfortunately I am unable to access data. I have shared my code below. How can I possibly scrape the website efficiently. Should I use selenium webdriver for this task ? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import requests
headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Referer': 'https://www.jobijoba.com/fr/query/?what=&where=Ile-de-france&where_type=region',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
}

data = {
  'where': 'Ile-de-france',
  'where_type': 'region',
  'perimeter': '20',
  'duration': '',
  'period': '',
  'publication': '',
  'contract': '',
  'formation': 'false',
  'jobbing': 'false',
  'page': '4',
  'editor_id': '54'
}

response = requests.post('https://www.jobijoba.com/fr/url_api', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script does give a response, which can be accessed as

```
response.json()
```

I don't have the context to tell how meaningful that response is, but there is a definitely a valid API response.

Comment: I am trying to get the underlying data of the website. The response from api doesnot consist of those. Is there a way I can get my desired data ?